# Using Index Cause MySQL Query Stuck For Infinite Time

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

I have few mysql tables with huge data. To speed up some frequent queries, I am creating indexes to make queries faster. I already did created few composite index which are working fine.

However, I am currently stuck on creating a two column index, which I targeted to make two queries faster. One of the queries running fine(and faster, of course), but other query is getting stuck in the following state:

[image]

The index created on (one foreign key(u2_.'service_id', u2_.'status') + one boolean) column. The query is as below:

```
SELECT u0_.value AS value0, u1_.property_uri AS property_uri1, count(u0_.id) AS sclr2,
  u2_.service_id AS sclr3 
FROM usc_connection_triple u0_ 
INNER JOIN usc_property u1_ 
  ON u0_.property_id = u1_.id AND (u1_.status = 1) 
INNER JOIN usc_account_connection u3_ 
  ON u0_.account_connection_id = u3_.id AND (u3_.status = 1) 
INNER JOIN usc_service_subscriber u2_ 
  ON ((u2_.id = u3_.account_1_id OR u2_.id = u3_.account_2_id)) 
WHERE (u1_.create_analytics = '1') AND (u0_.status = 1) AND (u2_.status = 1) 
GROUP BY u2_.service_id, u0_.property_id, u0_.value
```

I can't have a clue what I can do to resolve this? Can you please give some suggestion/idea how can I go ahead with this? As this suppose to improve two important queries, its kind of critical I need use this.

Update:
I realized, I wasn't properly descriptive about my idea of deadlock. Here is why I thought so:

before creating the index, this query was taking around 70 seconds to complete. after the index creation, I waited up to several hours, didn't help at all, which is very unusual. Later, I killed the php process and tried to drop the index, which also got stuck in the following state:

[image]

So, for this 'metadata lock' state, I though, the issue was may be related in getting lock for tables. Also, as its known that, over-indexing might create deadlock, I was thinking, probably that was my situation.

Do you think this might be related to some other aspect **like buffer pool config** etc? Or **any problem using a column in multiple secondary index**?

Comment: This isn't really a deadlock issue in itself.

Comment: Please put "EXPLAIN EXTENDED" in front of your query and post the output here.

Comment: I changed the title of this question. You don't have a deadlock, this is just a long-running SELECT query. Please learn what a [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) is before using that term.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by rewriting the query as:

```
    SELECT u0_.value AS value0, 
           u1_.property_uri AS property_uri1, count(u0_.id) AS sclr2,
           u2_.service_id AS sclr3 
      FROM usc_connection_triple u0_ 
INNER JOIN usc_property u1_ 
        ON u1_.id = u0_.property_id
       AND u1_.status = 1
       AND u1_.create_analytics = 1
INNER JOIN usc_account_connection u3_ 
        ON u3_.id = u0_.account_connection_id 
       AND u3_.status = 1 
INNER JOIN usc_service_subscriber u2_ 
        ON u2_.id IN (u3_.account_1_id,u3_.account_2_id)
       AND u2_.status = 1
     WHERE u0_.status = 1 
  GROUP BY u2_.service_id, u0_.property_id, u0_.value
```

Then I'd add composite indexes that cover the JOIN conditions to the relevant tables. You may have to hint these indexes in the query to get the optimizer to use them. `EXPLAIN EXTENDED ...` is the tool of choice for this.

**N.B.** I have changed the condition `u1_.create_analytics = '1'` to `u1_.create_analytics = 1` as I assumed this was a typo.

Comment: Thanks for giving some optimization suggestion, I really appreciate it. However, I am using DQL with filters etc, which is generating such sql query automatically itself. So, at this moment, I am trying to optimize with current existing query possible. However, any clue about the query stuck situation/how to debug/overcome it, would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Rana, even if you can't physically rewrite the query in your code.. breaking it down like this can still be useful. You also really need to run an `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` on the original query to find out what indexes it is using and which may be useful. Also, I would be wary of systems that generate such complex SQL without allowing you some input as to it's structure.. are you sure DQL doesn't let you move some WHERE conditions into the JOINs?